# Django Rest Framework what is the meaning of arguments being passed to the ModelSerializer?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to understand the arguments which are being passed into the `serializers.ListUserSerializer()`.  I understand that `last_five` is the data to be returned through the serializer.

Where I fail to understand is where this model has a to-many relationship.  From reading the DRF documentation, `many=True` is passed when the model has a to-many relationship.  However, I do not understand how this is specifying the to-many relationship.  I see a couple of possibilities . . .

- one to many between current user and all other users
- one to many between current user and `last_five` Users query

Also I am not quite understanding the `context` argument.  I think that it is simply the request call to the api being included in the payload to the client.

The code base for this is [here](https://github.com/nomadcoders/nomadgram)

```
    class ExploreUsers(APIView):

        def get(self, request, format=None):

            # the "-date_joined" specifies descending order vs "date_joined"
            last_five = models.User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')[:5]

            # many=True provides to-many relationship from one user to many users
            serializer = serializers.ListUserSerializer(
                last_five, many=True, context={"request": request})

            return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`many = True`**
By setting `many=True` you tell DRF that ***the object you are passing contains multiple items (a list of items)*** so DRF needs to serialize each item with serializer class (and `serializer.data` will be a list)

Here you are passing `queryset` which is a `list` like object (list of object of model class)

**`context`**
`context` is a (or should be) `dict`, which is passed to your `serializer` and you could access the `context data` anywhere in your serializer by **`self.context['key']`**

**EXAMPLE**

```
# serializer.py
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    age = serializers.SerializerMethodField(required=False)

    def get_age(self, age):
        if self.context['age']:
            return self.context['age']
        return None


# usage
sample_data = {"name": "your name"}
serializer = MySerializer(data=sample_data, context={'age': 12})
serializer.is_valid(True)
print(serializer.data)
```

Comment: So context is simply a dictionary to pass data into my serializer which I will want to use to access data relevant to the request.

Comment: Yeah.. Exactly. In case of generic views, that classes are passing `view` object and `request` object by default